# Error in Apollo Server deploy with AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

People, how are you? I have a query, I just implemented my API made with apollo server in an AWS Lambda. I used the official documentation as a guide, but I'm noticing that the context handling varies a bit. I have a doubt with the latter, since I made certain changes and everything works fine locally using "serverless offline", but once I deploy it doesn't. Apparently the authentication context that I generate does not finish reaching my query. If someone can guide me a bit with this, I will be very grateful.

This is my API index:

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-lambda');
const typeDefs = require('./db/schema');
const resolvers = require('./db/resolvers');
const db = require('./config/db');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });

db.conectDB();

// The ApolloServer constructor requires two parameters: your schema
// definition and your set of resolvers.
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: { 
    endpoint: "/graphql"
  },
  context: ({ event, context }) => {
    try {
      const token = event.headers['authorization'] || '';
      
      if(token){
        context.user = jwt.verify(token.replace('Bearer ',''), process.env.KEY_TOKEN);
      }
      
      return {
        headers: event.headers,
        functionName: context.functionName,
        event,
        context,
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
});

exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler({
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
  },
});
```

This is my query:

```js
        getUserByToken: async (_, {}, { context }) => {
            if(context)
                throw new Error((context ? 'context' : '') + ' ' + (context.user ? 'user' : ''));
            let user = await db.findOne('users',{ _id: ObjectId(context.user._id) });

            if(user.birthdate)
                    user.birthdate = user.birthdate.toString();

            if(user.password)
                user.password = true;
            else
                user.password = false;

            return user;
        }
```

My API response:
[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgtNz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're not calling getUserByToken in your context.  Is that correct?  So, I'm not sure how you're encountering this error.

Can I give you some pointers?

Connecting to your DB is probably (or it should be) asynchronous.  For that, I'd run your code like this:

```
db.connect()
  .then(() => {
   ... handle your request in here
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

I think you meant to call your getUserByToken in this line:

```
context.user = jwt.verify(token.replace('Bearer ',''), process.env.KEY_TOKEN);
```